# onkeypress is working but onblur is not

Tags: javascript, validation, input, onblur

I am using the below input field. Here the onkeypress is working fine for tab key and enter key but when I am trying to just create a alert form onblur it is not working at all. I moved the cursor pinting to another input field by mouse click but onblur is not firing at all.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" onkeypress="isDouble(document.getElementById('username'),event)" onblur="alert(1)" required/>
```

Not sure if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These all work, so not sure where the discrepancy is with the rest of your code and the input you provided.

```
<input onfocus="console.log('focus')" onkeyup="console.log('keyup')" onblur="console.log('blurred')" type="text">
```

Comment: got the problem. There is a span after the input field which is using onblur to show hints. if I comment that out it is working fine. But now, I am in mud, how to solve that?
<span class="hint">Please enter the username</span>

Comment: Could you just use a placeholder attribute? `<input placeholder="Please enter the username" ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" onkeypress="isDouble(document.getElementById('username'),event)" onblur="alert(1)" required/>
```

This works:
    (both onblur and isDouble fire):

```
function isDouble(arg) {
    alert('isDouble');
    return false; // remove this, and only isDouble() will fire.
}
```

Comment: Guess what I'm saying is, if your function is taking over and returning a value, the onblur event is going to be ignored. Seems like an easy assumption...however, no one here can see your code, so we's all just speculatin'

Comment: I am new to JS. you are saying that onblur would not work if function is returning a value?let me try that out.Thanks.

Comment: got the problem. There is a span after the input field which is using onblur to show hints. if I comment that out it is working fine. But now, I am in mud, how to solve that? <span class="hint">Please enter the username</span>

Comment: Would need to see more code, I think. I'm not positive how you're interacting with the input and span, as to why it's even part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/78N9A/1/ it seems to working

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" onkeypress="isDouble(document.getElementById('username'),event)" onblur="alert(1)" required/>
```

Comment: got the problem. There is a span after the input field which is using onblur to show hints. if I comment that out it is working fine. But now, I am in mud, how to solve that? <span class="hint">Please enter the username</span>